# morris.js chart in jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, morris.js

I am struggling with morris.js charts within jquery tabs:

http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default

The first chart shows fine but the other tabs only show the morris-hover:

[image: morris-hover].

EDIT: (Not sure why this stopped working - was working on post and picture is still live).

No errors in the console.  I am not the greatest with js but pretty certain all the chart code is fine because the charts show when taken out of the tabs.

The tab code seems fine as works with text.

I have seen dotted about a few mentions of using redraw() to fix this but not really sure how to and any jsfiddles that I find are offline or don't work.  Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128708/load-morris-js-graph-in-active-tab-bootstrap).

If anyone could offer me some guidance it would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
        <div id="tabs">
                        <div id="tabs-1" class="statdiv">
            <h4>Tab</h4>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="morris-line-chart"></div>
                            </div>
            </div>

                        <div id="tabs-2" class="statdiv">
            <h4>Tab 2</h4>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="morris-line-chart2"></div>
                            </div>
            </div>

                        <div id="tabs-3" class="statdiv">
            <h4>Tab 3</h4>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="morris-line-chart3"></div>
                            </div>
            </div>

                        <div id="tabs-4" class="statdiv">
            <h4>Tab 4</h4>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="morris-line-chart4"></div>
                            </div>
            </div>

            <ul class="navtab">
                <li class="stattab1 active"><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li class="stattab2"><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
                <li class="stattab3"><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
                <li class="stattab4"><a href="#tabs-4">Tab 4</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

JS for Charts:

```
$(function() {

Morris.Line({
    // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
    element: 'morris-line-chart',
    // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
    // the chart.
    data: [{
        d: '2012-10-01',
        visits: 802
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-02',
        visits: 783
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-03',
        visits: 820
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-04',
        visits: 839
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-05',
        visits: 792
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-06',
        visits: 859
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-07',
        visits: 790
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-08',
        visits: 1680
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-09',
        visits: 1592
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-10',
        visits: 1420
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-11',
        visits: 882
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-12',
        visits: 889
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-13',
        visits: 819
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-14',
        visits: 849
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-15',
        visits: 870
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-16',
        visits: 1063
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-17',
        visits: 1192
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-18',
        visits: 1224
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-19',
        visits: 1329
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-20',
        visits: 1329
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-21',
        visits: 1239
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-22',
        visits: 1190
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-23',
        visits: 1312
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-24',
        visits: 1293
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-25',
        visits: 1283
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-26',
        visits: 1248
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-27',
        visits: 1323
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-28',
        visits: 1390
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-29',
        visits: 1420
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-30',
        visits: 1529
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-31',
        visits: 1892
    }, ],
    // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-visitss.
    xkey: 'd',
    // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-visitss.
    ykeys: ['visits'],
    // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
    // chart.
    labels: ['Visits'],
    // Disables line smoothing
    smooth: false,
    resize: false
});

Morris.Line({
    // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
    element: 'morris-line-chart2',
    // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
    // the chart.
    data: [{
        d: '2012-10-01',
        visits: 802
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-02',
        visits: 783
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-03',
        visits: 820
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-04',
        visits: 839
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-05',
        visits: 792
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-06',
        visits: 859
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-07',
        visits: 790
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-08',
        visits: 1680
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-09',
        visits: 1592
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-10',
        visits: 1420
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-11',
        visits: 882
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-12',
        visits: 889
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-13',
        visits: 819
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-14',
        visits: 849
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-15',
        visits: 870
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-16',
        visits: 1063
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-17',
        visits: 1192
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-18',
        visits: 1224
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-19',
        visits: 1329
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-20',
        visits: 1329
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-21',
        visits: 1239
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-22',
        visits: 1190
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-23',
        visits: 1312
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-24',
        visits: 1293
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-25',
        visits: 1283
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-26',
        visits: 1248
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-27',
        visits: 1323
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-28',
        visits: 1390
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-29',
        visits: 1420
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-30',
        visits: 1529
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-31',
        visits: 1892
    }, ],
    // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-visitss.
    xkey: 'd',
    // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-visitss.
    ykeys: ['visits'],
    // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
    // chart.
    labels: ['Visits'],
    // Disables line smoothing
    smooth: false,
    resize: false
});


Morris.Line({
    // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
    element: 'morris-line-chart3',
    // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
    // the chart.
    data: [{
        d: '2012-10-01',
        visits: 802
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-02',
        visits: 783
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-03',
        visits: 820
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-04',
        visits: 839
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-05',
        visits: 792
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-06',
        visits: 859
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-07',
        visits: 790
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-08',
        visits: 1680
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-09',
        visits: 1592
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-10',
        visits: 1420
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-11',
        visits: 882
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-12',
        visits: 889
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-13',
        visits: 819
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-14',
        visits: 849
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-15',
        visits: 870
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-16',
        visits: 1063
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-17',
        visits: 1192
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-18',
        visits: 1224
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-19',
        visits: 1329
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-20',
        visits: 1329
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-21',
        visits: 1239
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-22',
        visits: 1190
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-23',
        visits: 1312
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-24',
        visits: 1293
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-25',
        visits: 1283
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-26',
        visits: 1248
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-27',
        visits: 1323
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-28',
        visits: 1390
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-29',
        visits: 1420
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-30',
        visits: 1529
    }, {
        d: '2012-10-31',
        visits: 1892
    }, ],
    // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-visitss.
    xkey: 'd',
    // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-visitss.
    ykeys: ['visits'],
    // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
    // chart.
    labels: ['Visits'],
    // Disables line smoothing
    smooth: false,
    resize: true
});

 Morris.Line({
    // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
    element: 'morris-line-chart4',
    // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
    // the chart.
    data: [{
        e: '2012-10-01',
        visit: 9
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-02',
        visit: 783
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-03',
        visit: 820
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-04',
        visit: 839
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-05',
        visit: 792
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-06',
        visit: 859
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-07',
        visit: 790
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-08',
        visit: 1680
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-09',
        visit: 1592
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-10',
        visit: 1420
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-11',
        visit: 882
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-12',
        visit: 889
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-13',
        visit: 819
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-14',
        visit: 849
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-15',
        visit: 870
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-16',
        visit: 1063
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-17',
        visit: 1192
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-18',
        visit: 1224
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-19',
        visit: 1329
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-20',
        visit: 1329
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-21',
        visit: 1239
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-22',
        visit: 1190
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-23',
        visit: 1312
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-24',
        visit: 1293
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-25',
        visit: 1283
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-26',
        visit: 1248
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-27',
        visit: 1323
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-28',
        visit: 1390
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-29',
        visit: 1420
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-30',
        visit: 1529
    }, {
        e: '2012-10-31',
        visit: 1892
    }, ],
    // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-visitss.
    xkey: 'e',
    // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-visitss.
    ykeys: ['visit'],
    // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
    // chart.
    labels: ['visit'],
    // Disables line smoothing
    smooth: false,
    resize: false
});


Morris.Donut({
    element: 'morris-donut-chart',
    data: [{
        label: "Download Sales",
        value: 12
    }, {
        label: "In-Store Sales",
        value: 30
    }, {
        label: "Mail-Order Sales",
        value: 20
    }],
    resize: true
});


Morris.Donut({
    element: 'morris-donut-chart2',
    data: [{
        label: "Download Sales",
        value: 1
    }, {
        label: "In-Store Sales",
        value: 30
    }, {
        label: "Mail-Order Sales",
        value: 20
    }],
    resize: true
});




});
```

EDIT: Found a lot more posts about this but all the answers point to a jsfiddle that is no longer available :(.

EDIT 2: Also found this however the jsfiddle doesn't actually show the graphs so looks broken also http://jsfiddle.net/rbsthlm/cD6dd/12/.  Can't seem to get redraw() to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rbsthlm/cD6dd/12/

```
<div id="monitor" class="panel panel-default tab-box">
<div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">
        <i class="fa fa-signal"></i>
        Monitoring report
    </h3>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"> <a href="#fuel-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-identifier="line, donut">Fuel data</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#co2-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-identifier="bar1">Co2 data</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="fuel-tab" class="tab-pane active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 chart">
                    <div class="caption">Fuel consumption last 12 months <span class="label label-default">Liter/100km</span>

                    </div>
                    <div id="fuel-consumption"></div>
                    <div class="legend"> <span id="city" class="label">City</span>
<span id="highway" class="label">Highway</span>
<span id="idle" class="label">Idle</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 chart">
                    <div class="caption">Fuel projection this month</div>
                    <div id="fuel-projection"></div>
                    <div class="legend"> <span id="projection" class="label">Projection</span>
<span id="today" class="label">Until today</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="co2-tab" class="tab-pane">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 chart">
                    <div class="caption">Monthly Co2 Emissions <span class="label label-default">g/km</span>

                    </div>
                    <div id="co2-emissions"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('ul.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
var types = $(this).attr("data-identifier");
var typesArray = types.split(",");
$.each(typesArray, function (key, value) {
    eval(value + ".redraw()");
})
});
// Morris graphs ---------------------------------------------------------- //
// on doc ready
$(function () {
// Fuel consumption //
// Data set for fuel consumption
var fuel_data = [{
    "period": "2013-01",
    "city": 66,
    "highway": 34,
    "idle": 9
}, {
    "period": "2013-02",
    "city": 62,
    "highway": 33,
    "idle": 8
}, {
    "period": "2013-03",
    "city": 61,
    "highway": 32,
    "idle": 7
}, {
    "period": "2013-04",
    "city": 66,
    "highway": 32,
    "idle": 6
}, {
    "period": "2013-05",
    "city": 67,
    "highway": 31,
    "idle": 5
}, {
    "period": "2013-06",
    "city": 68,
    "highway": 43,
    "idle": 7
}, {
    "period": "2013-07",
    "city": 62,
    "highway": 32,
    "idle": 5
}, {
    "period": "2013-08",
    "city": 61,
    "highway": 32,
    "idle": 5
}, {
    "period": "2013-09",
    "city": 58,
    "highway": 32,
    "idle": 7
}, {
    "period": "2013-10",
    "city": 60,
    "highway": 32,
    "idle": 7
}, {
    "period": "2013-11",
    "city": 60,
    "highway": 32,
    "idle": 6
}, {
    "period": "2013-12",
    "city": 62,
    "highway": 32,
    "idle": 8
}];
// Line chart parameters for fuel consumption
var fuel_consumption = {
    element: 'fuel-consumption',
    hideHover: 'auto',
    data: fuel_data,
    xkey: 'period',
    xLabels: 'month',
    ykeys: ['city', 'highway', 'idle'],
    postUnits: ' l/100km',
    labels: ['City', 'Highway', 'Idle'],
    resize: true,
    lineColors: ['#A52A2A', '#72A0C1', '#7BB661']
    //yLabelFormat: function(y) { return y.toString() + ' l/100km'; }
}

// Make a line chart from the parameters
line = Morris.Line(fuel_consumption)
// / Fuel consumption //

// Fuel projection //
// Data set for fuel projection
var projection_data = [{
    label: 'Until today',
    value: 180
}, {
    label: 'Projected',
    value: 400
}, ]
// Donut chart parameters for fuel projection
var fuel_projection = {
    element: 'fuel-projection',
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true,
    data: projection_data,
    colors: ['#7BB661', '#72A0C1'],
    formatter: function (y) {
        return y + " liters"
    }
}

// Make a donut chart from the parameters
donut = Morris.Donut(fuel_projection)
// / Fuel projection //

// Fuel emissions //
// Data set for fuel emissions
var co2_data = [{
    month: 'Jan',
    emissions: 35
}, {
    month: 'Feb',
    emissions: 37
}, {
    month: 'Mar',
    emissions: 40
}, {
    month: 'Apr',
    emissions: 38
}, {
    month: 'Maj',
    emissions: 39
}, {
    month: 'Jun',
    emissions: 42
}, {
    month: 'Jul',
    emissions: 37
}, {
    month: 'Aug',
    emissions: 65
}, {
    month: 'Sep',
    emissions: 38
}, {
    month: 'Okt',
    emissions: 45
}, {
    month: 'Nov',
    emissions: 41
}, {
    month: 'Dec',
    emissions: 41
}]
//Bar chart parameters for CO2 emissions
var co2_emissions = {
    element: 'co2-emissions',
    resize: true,
    data: co2_data,
    xkey: 'month',
    ykeys: ['emissions'],
    labels: ['Co2 emissions'],
    barRatio: 0.4,
    xLabelAngle: 35,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    postUnits: ' g/km',
    formatter: function (y) {
        return y + " g/km"
    }
}

// Make a bar chart from the parameters
bar1 = Morris.Bar(co2_emissions)
// / Fuel emisisons //
});
// / Morris graphs -------------------------------------------------------- //
```

It only drew half the chart though - which is where this came in handy:

```
#chartelementid svg {width:100%;}
```