# Bootstrap carousel with Morris JS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have looked at the link you provided
[Bootstrap carousel has conflict with morris.js chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852281/bootstrap-carousel-has-conflict-with-morris-js-chart)
and saw that the response was to use the link to the tabpane jsfiddle. I tried to do that and still have issues. I was wondering if you maybe had been able to make it work?

Comment: Who is this addressed to?!

Comment: Im sorry, This was my first post on stack, I need to get better at this. This is addressed to http://stackoverflow.com/users/1773793/gigi-wu Who posed the same issue that i was running into.